# Creating a Title Page Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

Got a question on some android manifest and activity coordination. I have created an app that goes straight to the main activity, from which the user can interact with the app. I want to create an activity that displays a simple title of the app (maybe with a pic, but that's later...), then after a few second delay switches into the main activity. Here's what I have so far...

TitleActivity:

```
public class TitleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
...
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="khandy.application.convertible"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="khandy.application.convertible.TitleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="khandy.application.convertible.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
...
```

What happens on startup is that none of my views/widgets show on the title_activity while the 3 second delay happens, then it switches into the main activity. Then when I press the android back button i retreat back into the title activity, which runs with the views/widgets. I'm fairly sure that the views/widgets not appearing has something to do with my very coarse multithreading...

So, my questions are:

1. How do I get my views/widgets to appear when the title activity
   is first opened?
2. How can I set the main activity to simply exit the app when the
   back button is pressed? That is, how can I use the back button in
   the main activity to return to the android home screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finish titleactivity after mainactivity launch, this solves question 2. use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

for question 1, use following code

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity{

private SplashHandler mSplashHandler = new SplashHandler();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    mSplashHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SplashHandler.TIMER_EXPIRED, 5);
}




class SplashHandler extends Handler {
    static final int TIMER_EXPIRED = 100;
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case TIMER_EXPIRED:
            Intent in = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mSplashHandler = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want a SplashScreen I think:

```
public class TitleActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);



       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                 Intent intent = new Intent(TitleActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                 TitleActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                 TitleActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 3000);

    }
}
```